# Getting rid of the high volume warning

Tags: notifications, audio, volume, alert

Whenever I have to reboot my phone, shortly after it gives me a warning about volume being too high and decides to set it to 13. It's annoying because it often happens when I'm driving (and therefore controlling the volume from my car).

Is there any way I can tell my phone that I already have a mom and that this repeated warning is unwelcome?

My phone is a Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview. I'm in Canada but I've set the regional settings to US in order to be able to use the beta version of Cortana.

Comment: Currently, I do not think there is a way. We could develop a solution to bypass that, but there is no default solution for this, I believe.

Comment: What phone model do you use? And what region are you from or have got the phone from?

Comment: @VivekParekh I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reset your phone! This warning will ALWAYS show up as far as I'm aware. It seems to not happen so often anymore after the WP8.1 update. Also, if you do not restart your phone very often, it should not happen as much. It seems to just happen a few times after startup.

Answer (score 0):

The warning should only show up one or two times. Try making a factory reset of your phone since something seems broken. If it does not help I recommend going to your reseller and have it repaired/exchanged.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been a little more precise: it shows up after rebooting my phone, which happens if the OS crashes, the battery died or an update is installed.

Comment: Ok. Tried resetting your phone?

Comment: No, and I won't either unless somebody can point me to a resource that indicates it could very well resolve this particular problem.

Comment: This will not solve your problem, the OS is for some reason designed to do this and will periodically keep reminding you. It will happen more than "one or two times". A factory reset will lose any data on your phone and you will not solve the issue.